# Why python multiprocessing manager produce threading locks?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing, locks

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.Manager().Lock()
<thread.lock object at 0x7f64f7736290>
>>> type(multiprocessing.Lock())
<class 'multiprocessing.synchronize.Lock'>
```

Why the object produced by a manager is a `thread.lock` and not a `multiprocessing.synchronize.Lock` as it would be expected from a `multiprocessing` object?

Comment: Managed objects are always proxies. I see that there are differences between `multiprocessing.Lock` and `threading.Lock` that may be significant. I guess you'd normally use `multiprocessing.Lock()` unless you absolutely must have a `threading.Lock()` object, at which point the manager makes sure it is synchronised across processes for you?

Comment: At any rate, why did you expect the manager to return a `multiprocessing.Lock` object? You don't need to manage that object, it already is multiprocessing-aware.

Comment: I think you gave me the answer. The manager goal is actually to proxy non multiprocessing-aware objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed objects are always proxies; the goal of the manager is to make non-multiprocessing-aware objects into multiprocessing aware.

There is no point in doing this for `multiprocessing.Lock()` objects; these are implemented using [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) and are fully multiprocessing capable without assistance.

`threading.Lock` on the other hand is not multiprocessing aware; there are some differences between `threading.Lock()` objects and `multiprocessing.Lock()`; the latter supports a timeout when acquiring a lock, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not *expected* since the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Lock) clearly states that `Lock()`

> Create a shared `threading.Lock` object and return a proxy for it.

As to *why* it returns a threading.Lock instead of a multiprocessing object is a different story I unfortunately can't answer.